# How to change color in Material Components PROGRAMMATICALLY on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-design-library, material-components-android

I'm looking for a solution to change the color of some Android Material Components layout objects. **How can I change the color of text or borders in a Material Button programmatically?** All functions like `MaterialButton.setTexColor()` do not work. Same thing for the StrokeColor. The change must be made logically, directly from code. **No XML styles, colors must be able to change in live, based on values read from a database.**

Things like these don't work :

```
//renewSetDate is a Material Button Object
renewSetDate.strokeColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED)
renewSetDate.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
```

This is the XML Layout for the Material Button

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                        android:id="@+id/addSubs_btnSet_date"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                        android:text="Imposta data di rinnovo abbonamento"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addSubs_detailTitle"
                        app:strokeColor="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Colors must be read from templates saved in a database. I can't create an XML Style for each of the template.

I find it really annoying to have to change the layout colors only by who knows what attributes in an XML template.

These are the dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: Something like `button.setStrokeColor(AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(this, R.color.button_selector));` and
        `button.setTextColor(AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(this,R.color.button_selector));` work.

Comment: But I read the colors from the database records in the form of hexadecimal numbers like #A45B01. So I can't use R.color.xxxxxxxx . I can't use any XML file at all, style or color... all the colors will be insert in the buttons at runtime, when I open the Activity, but reading the data from the DB.

Comment: I think the problem is in the libraries, and in the way they (google devs) defined the properties of the material objects... i think that i will use the standard objects for the layout at this point...

Comment: Try to use the 1.1.0-beta02 of the material library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this was completely answered yet or not.

I was having the same issue and I ended up doing:

```
button.strokeColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED)
button.strokeWidth = 1
```

And that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using MaterilButton and Kotlin, I will write some options you can use:

```
binding.buttonCancelRequest.isClickable=false      

binding.buttonCancelRequest.background.setColorFilter(Color.GRAY,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)
    
binding.buttonCancelRequest.strokeColor= ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GRAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the color in this way:

```
//From RGB
int colorRGB = Color.rgb(255,0,0);

//From HEX String
int colorHEX = Color.parseColor("#FF11AA");
```

Then to define the border color in the MaterialButton you can use the **`setStrokeColor`** method.

```
int[][] states = new int[][] {
    new int[] { android.R.attr.state_checked},  // checked
    new int[] { -android.R.attr.state_checked}  // checked false
};

int[] colors = new int[] {
    colorRGB,
    colorHEX
};

ColorStateList myColorSelector = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
button.setStrokeColor(myColorSelector);
```

For the **text color** you can use something similar with the **`setTextColor`** method.
Your selector should handle these states:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="1.00" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_checkable="true" android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.60" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_checkable="true" android:state_checked="false" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="1.00" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

Something like:

```
int[][] states =  new int[][]{
    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checkable,android.R.attr.state_checked,android.R.attr.state_enabled},
    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checkable,-android.R.attr.state_checked,android.R.attr.state_enabled}, 
    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled},
    new int[]{} 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```
btn.setStrokeColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.<value>)));
btn.setStrokeWidth(2);
```