# setStrokeColor not working programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-button

I'm trying to set my color for the outline of my button, but I don't get it to work

I'm using material button and when I use

```
  button.setStrokeColorResource(Color.parseColor(#e4dcd4))
```

is not working and tells me this

> Expected a color resource id (R.color.) but received an RGB integer

I tried almost everything I could found about in stack, but I can't get it to set this strokeColor programmatically

### Edit

Almost all setColors use @ColorInt , but this strokeColor uses @ColorRes, which is not working for me, also there is setStrokeColor

```
public void setStrokeColor(@Nullable ColorStateList strokeColor) {
    if (isUsingOriginalBackground()) {
      materialButtonHelper.setStrokeColor(strokeColor);
    }
  }
```

But I can't get it to work either.

Comment: You might try `
button.setStrokeColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.your_color_xml));`

Comment: In the first method you have to use R.color.mycolor or check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58803115/2016562)

Answer (score 5):

It worked like this

```
val colorInt = Color.parseColor("#e4dcd4")
            val csl = ColorStateList.valueOf(colorInt)
            my_button.strokeColor = csl
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try this

```
button.setStrokeColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.your_color_xml));
```

Other way you can do is

```
ShapeDrawable gradientDrawable = (ShapeDrawable)button.getBackground(); 
gradientDrawable.setStroke(2, your_color);
```

Also as @Gabriele said you can get an int as a color as :

```
//From RGB
int colorRGB = Color.rgb(255,0,0);

//From HEX String
int colorHEX = Color.parseColor("#FF11AA");
```

Comment: @SNM Have you solved this? In order to help other people if this helped you feel free to upvote and mark this as a correct answer. Thanks :)+

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the width of the stroke because the default value is 0.

```
<Button 
app:strokeWidth="2dp"
../>

button.strokeColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#e4dcd4"))
```

or

// if color define in color.xml

```
 button.strokeColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.yourColorCOde))
```

// if you have different state and you want to set programmatically then do as :-

```
 var states = arrayOf(
            intArrayOf(R.attr.state_enabled),
            intArrayOf(-R.attr.state_enabled),
            intArrayOf(-R.attr.state_checked),
            intArrayOf(R.attr.state_pressed)
        )
```

// Color list  define respect of state

```
 var colors = intArrayOf(
        Color.BLACK,
        Color.RED,
        Color.GREEN,
        Color.BLUE
    )
```

// Set stroke color

```
button.strokeColor = ColorStateList(states, colors)
```